# In TWiki, how to sort rows of a table by multiple columns?

Tags: twiki

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/TablePlugin explains how to sort a table in TWiki by `initsort`. But how to break tie with the values in a second column?

Answer (score 2):

Best to ask TWiki support questions in the support forum on TWiki.org.

The TablePlugin does not support sorting by more than one column.

You could enhance the plugin (and contribute back the enhancements).

Alternatively, look into a pure JavaScript solution, such as [Sorting HTML table by two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642295/sorting-html-table-by-two-columns)

Comment: Thanks. But how to embed the JavaScript function into the particular TWiki page that contains the table?

Comment: Do a raw edit on any TWiki topic, and add any html/css/js code you like.

Comment: Peter Thoeny answers a question about TWiki and doesn't get upvoted, what a time to be alive. But now I need the answer so I get to upvote!